# Adding and Removing items from a list using provider flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, provider

I'm making favorite list which contains the user favorite journeys using provider then I will display these journeys in the favorite journeys screen.

Favorite.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Favorite extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Text date;
  final Text time;
  final Text source;
  final Text destination;
  final Text price;

  Favorite(this.date, this.time, this.source, this.destination, this.price);
}

class Following extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Favorite> list = [];
  add(favorite) {
    list.add(favorite);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  remove(favorite) {
    list.remove(favorite);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

journeys.dart (Which shows all journeys):

```
   FirebaseAnimatedList(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      query: Consts.journeyRef.child("journeys"),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                          Animation animation, int index) {
                        try {
                          return Consumer<Following>(
                            builder:
                                (BuildContext context, value, child) {
                              return Dismissible(
                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                secondaryBackground: buildSwipeActionRight(),
                                background: buildSwipeActionLeft(),
                                child: ListView(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      eachTile(
                                        following,
                                        Favorite(
                                        Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                                          snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathDateJourney]),
                                        Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                                            snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathTimeJourney]),
                                        Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                                            snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathSourceCity]),
                                        Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                                            snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathDestinationCity]),
                                        Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                                            snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathPriceJourney]),),)
        
                                    ]),
                                onDismissed: (direction) =>
                                    dismissItem(context, index, direction),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        } catch (e) {
                          customSnackBar(context, e.toString(), 3, Colors.white24, Colors.brown, 17);
                          return const Text(
                              "We Can't show you information disabled by the Administrator");
                        }
                      }),
```

eachTile.dart:

```dart
ListTile eachTile(following, favorite) {
  return ListTile(
    leading: Column(
      children: [
        favorite.date,
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        favorite.time,
      ],
    ),
    title: Row(
      children: [
        favorite.source,
        const SizedBox(
          width: 50,
        ),
        favorite.price
      ],
    ),
    subtitle: favorite.destination,
    trailing: IconButton(
      icon: following.list.contains(favorite)
          ? const Icon(Icons.favorite)
          : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined),
      onPressed: () {
        print(following.list.contains(favorite));
// this print statement always false
        if (following.list.contains(favorite)) {
          following.remove(favorite);
        } else {
          following.add(favorite);
        }
        print(following.list.contains(favorite));
// this print statement always true
        print(following.list);
// this print statement print the list and in each time the code execute new instance added to the list
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

This code is working fine as adding the journey to the list but the Problem is that when you click on the favorite icon again the condition

> `following.list.contains(favorite)`

is returning false (Which means this object is not in the list but that's wrong I try to print the list and there is an instance) it seem that the following instance changed but I didn't create any new instance I think it is creating new different instance in each time.

What is the best way to add and remove items to the favorite list using provider?

the output:

```
I/flutter (  578): false
I/flutter (  578): true
I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite']
V/AutofillManager(  578): requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
I/flutter (  578): false
I/flutter (  578): true
I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite']
V/AutofillManager(  578): requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
I/flutter (  578): false
I/flutter (  578): true
I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I'm making equal-to operator between two object and it's returning false that is because all objects in the dart language except the primitive data types like string, int, and double... are not equal to each other since no == operator is overridden and set to it, and this include also collections like lists, maps...
the solution is to override the `==` operator in Favorite class:

```
class Favorite{
  final Text date;
  final Text time;
  final Text source;
  final Text destination;
  final Text price;
  Favorite(this.date, this.time, this.source, this.destination, this.price);@override
  bool operator == (Object other) {
    return other is Favorite && date.toString() == other.date.toString() && time.toString() == other.time.toString() && source.toString() == other.source.toString() && destination.toString() == other.destination.toString() && price.toString() == other.price.toString();
  }
}
```

now when I run `following.list.contains(favorite)` or following.list[0]==favorite in listTile Widget it will return true.
and that's it

Answer (score 1):

first clean the code here in journey.dart you are using both the methods of provider you can archive this task by

1.you can use consumer widget or provider.of(context) but you are using both ways to call only Following provider

2.in journey.dart if you decided to use consumer then in  `(BuildContext context, Following value, Widget? child)` you can use value and child directly no need to write data types in front eg..  `(BuildContext context,  value, child)`

3.can you display your console output

Comment: Thanks I delete provider.of(context) and I use value and child directly

Comment: the output:
> I/flutter (  578): false
> I/flutter (  578): true
> I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite']
> I/flutter (  578): false
> I/flutter (  578): true
> I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite']
> I/flutter (  578): false
> I/flutter (  578): true
> I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite']

Comment: update the code please to get better answers

Comment: I update it thank you

Comment: once print(following.list); this in else statement and tell me the result

Comment: the output when print(following.list); this in else statement:

> I/flutter (  578): []
> V/AutofillManager(  578): requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
> I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite']
> V/AutofillManager(  578): requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
> I/flutter (  578): [Instance of 'Favorite', Instance of 'Favorite']

Comment: ok as you said This code is working fine as adding the journey to the list but the Problem is that when you click on the favorite icon again the condition

following.list.contains(favorite)
is returning false ....here as per my knowledge code is working as expected because you are using ' if (following.list.contains(favorite)) {
          following.remove(favorite);
        } else {
          following.add(favorite);
        }'this condition  select multiple items as favourite and remove one item as favourite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248661/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-and-saad-tabban).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make a change, you should call `notifyListeners();`. An example Implementation would be: 
Inside your Provider Class:

```
void add(int n) {
   myList.add(n);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks miro I'm using notify listener in the Provider class which is in the Following class